# Is there a simpler way to return fields from static function?

Tags: c#

I often want to parse a string into various bits and have a readable way to return them.

I like this approach, but it involves creating a specific class

```
long orderID = Utils.UnTradeIdent(tradeIdent).OrderID;
```

In Utils.cs:

```
    public class TradeIdentData
    {
        public string AccountIdent;
        public long OrderID;
        public string SubID;
    }

    public static TradeIdentData UnTradeIdent(string tradeIdent)
    {
        TradeIdentData tradeIdentData = new TradeIdentData();

        var parts = tradeIdent.Split('!');
        tradeIdentData.AccountIdent = parts[0];
        if (parts[1].Contains("."))
        {
            var bits = parts[1].Split('.');
            tradeIdentData.OrderID = long.Parse(bits[1]);
            tradeIdentData.SubID = bits[1];
        }
        else
        {
            tradeIdentData.OrderID = long.Parse(parts[1]);
            tradeIdentData.SubID = "";
        }

        return tradeIdentData;

    }
```

Comment: With the upcoming C# 7 you could use the built in tuple feature: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1936/c-sharp-7-0-features/6329/language-support-for-tuples#t=201609211453403656236

Comment: Describing what you return, is not a bad idea..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A separate class with well-named properties (which you are already using) is currently the most readable way of doing this.

In C# 7 you will be able to use tuples for return values, like so:

```
public static (string AccountIdent, string OrderID, string SubID) UnTradeIdent(string tradeIdent)
{
    string accountIdent, orderID, subID ;

    ... Code to initialise accountIdent, orderID and subID appropriately ...

    // Now return the data as a tuple:       

    return (accountIdent, orderID, subID);
}
```

You can consume this as follows:

```
long orderID = Utils.UnTradeIdent(tradeIdent).OrderID;
```

Or if you want all the values:

```
var result = Utils.UnTradeIdent(tradeIdent);
// Use result.OrderId, result.SubID or result.AccountIdent
```

This is not going to be available until some time next year, though.

Also, even though this new tuple support makes it more convenient to WRITE the code, it doesn't let you document it using XML comments as well. Spending the time to write a simple and well-documented class will still often be better than using the new C# 7 tuple support.

[See here for more details](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `out` keyword to pass arguments by reference, see MSDN article [out (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx):

```
public static void UnTradeIdent(string tradeIdent, out string AccountIdent, out long OrderID, out string SubID)
{
    var parts = tradeIdent.Split('!');
    AccountIdent = parts[0];
    if (parts[1].Contains("."))
    {
        var bits = parts[1].Split('.');
        OrderID = long.Parse(bits[1]);
        SubID = bits[1];
    }
    else
    {
        OrderID = long.Parse(parts[1]);
        SubID = "";
    }
}
```

**UPDATED** with suggestion from comments:

```
public static bool UnTradeIdent(string tradeIdent, out string AccountIdent, out long OrderID, out string SubID)
{
    bool result = false;
    AccountIdent = "";
    OrderID = 0;
    SubID = "";

    try
    {
        var parts = tradeIdent.Split('!');
        AccountIdent = parts[0];
        if (parts[1].Contains("."))
        {
            var bits = parts[1].Split('.');
            OrderID = long.Parse(bits[1]);
            SubID = bits[1];
        }
        else
        {
            OrderID = long.Parse(parts[1]);
            SubID = "";
        }
    }
    catch(ArgumentNullException ane)
    {
        // Handle parsing exception

    }
    catch (FormatException fe)
    {
        // Handle parsing exception
    }
    catch (OverflowException oe)
    {
        // Handle parsing exception
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I would extend this method to return a bool when it could be parsed/indicates that the `out` values are valid. Like the `int.TryParse()` etc

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Excellent suggestion, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple to do just by changing the return type to dynamic and using an anonymous class

```
public static dynamic UnTradeIdent(string tradeIdent)
{
    var value1 = //parselogic
    var value2 = //parselogic
    return new { Identity = value1, Item2 = value2};
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic!

Comment: I would avoid using `dynamic`, if no script languages are involved. It usually implies a bad design. There is no compile-time check on them, which could result in runtime errors.

Comment: @ManInMoon It's not fantastic, it's really not. Don't use that. The compiler will let you use any old name for the properties of the return value, and it will give you an error at compile time if it's wrong. And it will use the compiler at runtime to generate the code for `dynamic`.

Comment: "it usually implies a bad design" thats a bit of a sweeping statement. It can be quite handy to do things like this, and it doesn't always mean a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making additional static methods. Your current implementation is cleaner when you require all of the returned properties, but something like below might be appropriate when you only need one of them.

```
public static string TradeIdentToAccountIdent(string tradeIdent)
{
    var parts = tradeIdent.Split('!');

    return parts[0];
}

public static long TradeIdentToOrderID(string tradeIdent)
{
    var parts = tradeIdent.Split('!');
    if (parts[1].Contains("."))
    {
        var bits = parts[1].Split('.');

        return long.Parse(bits[1]); // Taken from your example, should probably be bits[0]?
    }
    else
        return long.Parse(parts[1]);
}

// My own take on it this time, you could obviously use your logic as well.
public static string TradeIdentToSubID(string tradeIdent)
{
    var order = tradeIdent.Split('!')[1];

    if (order.Contains("."))
        return order.Split('.')[1];
    else
        return String.Empty;
}
```